# How do I use the Core Plot framework with Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, core-plot

How do I install the Core Plot framework into Xcode 4?

[This older tutorial](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-core-plot-in-an-iphone-application) has instructions on how to install it for Xcode 3, but I could not find any similar instructions for Xcode 4. What do I need to do in order to use this framework with the newer Xcode?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I made one here that followed what I did:

http://recycled-parts.blogspot.com/2011/07/setting-up-coreplot-in-xcode-4.html

Hope it helps!

Comment: I will also mention, the code for that site is for the old version. Check down in the thread for posts on the new code. It will help a lot in your struggles.

Comment: `http://recycled-parts.blogspot.com/` This blog is open to invited readers only...

Comment: I'm sorry. The blog has been switched to public, thank you for notifying me.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that I was unable to set up core plot project for the reason that I had corrupt example project which code I was using.

This are the steps:

- open a project
- add quartzcore framework
- add other linker flags: -ObjC -all_load
- add CorePlot.xcodeproj to existing project (drag and drop)
- add sample class (from examples folder, drag and drop)
- drag coreplot framework from added CorePlot.xcodeproj to linked frameworks

in IB

- drop object and associate it to sample class
- drop custom view to window and associate it vith CPTLayerHostingView
- connect object and custom view

And hat is that (may sound complicated, but can be done in under a minute)

Steps can be taken in any order, except last few.

Everithing is very similar to instructions at: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-core-plot-in-an-iphone-application except the way it is done in xcode4 is actually easier.

Here are screenshoots that clarify the above steps: http://www.optimae.biz/data/stackoverflow/coreplot.pdf

Hope this will help someone.

---